# Remove path from .libPaths() so just a single non standard path is left as library

Tags: r

I want to have a single library in R, which is not the default.
 The idea is, to push the needed Rprofiles or environment variables out to all network computers, such that all use the same R-respository.

I added an environment variable to add the new lib, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the standard library. I don't know how to edit the Rprofile.

```
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS_USER")
[1] "X:/R Repository Database"
> Sys.getenv("R_LIBS")
[1] "X:/R Respository Database"
> .libPaths()
[1] "X:/R Repository Database"           "C:/ProgramFiles/R/R-3.2.5/library"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the *system* setting for the package directory (`$R_HOME/library`), nor should you. That directory contains the packages that come with R, including the base package, and it's likely that R would fail to start correctly if you tried pointing it elsewhere.

But this is really a distraction. The main sources of incompatibilities come from using different versions of *user-contributed* packages. Those you can control by having a site-wide package directory, which is what you've done. Incompatibilities due to different versions of *system* packages are really down to using different versions of R; if you want to avoid those, then install only one R version.